# mysql show all column names in array php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a mysql table with columns: `Date, Jack, John, Amy`.
I want to show the column names (only the names!) in an array using php.

So the result should be an array like this:

```
$array = array('Date', 'Jack', 'John', 'Amy');
```

So when I do `echo $array[1];` for example, the output should be 'Jack'.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: if colomns names are there then you need right!!!!!!!

Comment: EXPLAIN tablename ... can be a solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Only column names as in array mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955650/get-only-column-names-as-in-array-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
$table_column = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM YourTableName"); 
$tableArr = array();
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($table_column))
{
    $tableArr[] = $row1['Field'];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($tableArr);
```

Comment: how do i display it in an array then?